# Accessing objects in a datalist through Linq

Tags: linq

I have the following Linq statement

```
from DataListItem dli in dlAttachments.Items
select new Objects.BHAttachment
 {
  Name = ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")).HasFile ? ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")).FileName : (((HyperLink)dli.FindControl("hypCurrentAttachment")).Text != null ? ((HyperLink)dli.FindControl("hypCurrentAttachment")).Text : ""),
  Path = ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")).HasFile ? ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")).PostedFile.FileName : "",
  FileUpload = ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")).HasFile ? ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment")) : new FileUpload(),
  DocumentType = ((Label)dli.FindControl("lblType")).Text,
  URL = ""
 }
```

And it works, very well. My question is about the constant re-referencing the FileUpload object. I am recreating (and refinding it) 6 times. Is there a way to set it once within Linq and refer to that single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `let` statement to create a variable

```
from DataListItem dli in dlAttachments.Items
let x = ((FileUpload)dli.FindControl("fuAttachment"))
select new Objects.BHAttachment
{
    Name = (x.HasFile ? (x.FileName : (((HyperLink)dli.FindControl("hypCurrentAttachment")).Text != null ? ((HyperLink)dli.FindControl("hypCurrentAttachment")).Text : "")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, via the [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx).  You can do this for all of your objects:

```
from DataListItem dli in dlAttachments.Items
let fileUpload = dli.FindControl("fuAttachment") as FileUpload
let hyperlink = dli.FindControl("hypCurrentAttachment") as Hyperlink
let label = dli.FindControl("lblType") as Label
select new Objects.BHAttachment
 {
    Name = fileUpload.HasFile ? fileUpload.FileName : (hyperlink.Text ?? ""),
    ...
```